# What is wrong with this PHP echo line?

Tags: php

Is there something wrong with the line beginning with `echo`? I'm getting this error but I'm not sure how I can change it: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' on line 74`

```
while ( have_rows('stills') ) : the_row();

    // display a sub field value
    echo '<li><img src="' . the_sub_field('still'); . '" alt="<?php the_sub_field('project_name'); ?>-still"></li>'

endwhile;
```

I changed it to this but it's still not outputting correctly: `echo '<li><img src="' . the_sub_field('still') . '"></li>';`

Also, if this isn't the area to ask for help on these types of questions, where can I ask?

Edit: Tried satyr607's solution and this is how it's outputted.

```
<div class="project-stills">
    <h3>Stills</h3>

    http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/17.jpg

    <li><img src="" alt="-still"></li>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a `;` where it doesn't belong.

Comment: `<?php` in the echo, think about it

Comment: @Dagon I got rid of the php statement but it's still not outputting correctly. Can you help?

Comment: works for me:http://codepad.viper-7.com/Eem6Ty

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo '<li><img src="' . the_sub_field('still') . '" alt="' . the_sub_field('project_name') . '-still"></li>';
```

watch your escaping.

Comment: I get an error saying there's an unexpected `.` on that line.

Comment: semi colon in between: `('still'); . `

Comment: that line re-introduced the `;` which ends the echo, and `.` is an invalid command.  Note that you also should html-escape scrings being sent to a browser, since quotes in the project name for example might break the html.

Comment: Yeah, that was my bad. Was coding blind (maybe a bit tipsy :P).

Comment: For some odd reason, it's still not outputting correctly. If you check my post above, I updated it with what the code outputs.

Comment: the_sub_field is using return and not echo ?

Comment: in the future if your referring to a ,wordpress or wordpress plug-in, tag it word-press (then i can ignore it)